# Diagonal arrow using Tikz

Tags: tikz-arrows

[image]

I intend to generate this sketch using tikz, but was unable to do so. I was trying to fiddle with the following code:

```
 \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
   \usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
 A \arrow[rd] \arrow[r, "\phi"] & B \\
& C
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

I need some help here. Also a good reference for tikz would be appreciated, specifically, I am not able to understand the function of "&" in tikz environment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`tikz-cd` documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd)

You have to think on your diagram as an array, with rows and columns. In your case, 2 rows and 4 columns.

So, at position `(i,j)` you can start an arrow pointing to another position `(k,l)`, where you specify if the ending position is `left`, `right`, `up` or `down`, or even combinations of those.

In your example, and arrow from `B` to `E` should be `rd` (right and down).

Observe that to create cells in the array you change columns with `&` and change rows with `\\`.

As usual, it is easy to change colours also, for example, `\arrow[rd, red]`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
 A  \arrow[r, "\phi"] & B \arrow[rd] \arrow[r] & C \arrow[r] & D \\
 & & E
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Complete, concise and exhaustive answer.